# Can I do this: mysite.com?&var1=value1&var2=value2

Tags: javascript, url, ampersand

Basically, I wrote this code:

```
var paramStr = '';
for (var n in params) {
    paramStr += '&' + n + '=' + params[n];
}
xhr.open(method, url + '?' + paramStr);
```

Do I need to remove the first ampersand or can I leave it as is with no side effects?

Comment: Just remove it using paramStr.substr(1) and it will be both nice and workable :)

Comment: Don't forget to URL encode parameters.

Comment: Wow, lots of interesting solutions in no time. I just love SO :) Thank you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leave it as is.

`www.something.com?&something=something_else` is a valid url

But what I would do so it looks right is add a dummy param:

```
var paramStr = '?dummy'; //or any other value
for (var n in params) {
    paramStr += '&' + n + '=' + params[n];
}
xhr.open(method, url + paramStr);
```

or [@slobodan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512039/slobodan)'s solution:

```
var paramStr = '?'; 
for (var n in params) {
    paramStr += n + '=' + params[n] + '&'; 
    // because you can have a `&` at the end
}
xhr.open(method, url + paramStr);
```

Comment: or change it to paramStr += n + '=' + params[n] + '&';

Answer (score 3):

There should be no problem with a preceding ampersand.  However, in this sort of situation, I like to push the values to an array and join them afterwards, then you don't have to worry about it:

```
var paramArr = [];
for (var n in params) {
    paramArr.push(n + '=' + params[n]);
}
xhr.open(method, url + '?' + paramArr.join("&"));
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rq7bA/**

Answer (score 2):

You can leave that. But you can remove it very simply: `paramStr.substr(1)`

What you might need though is a `/` after `.com`. Maybe not...

**edit**
It's not a 'valid' URL without the `/`, but all browsers (incl the XHR class) fix that for you automatically.

Comment: Because your browser fixes that. A URL path (as in `GET ... HTTP/1.1`) can't start with a `?` though. Must always start with a `/`. Details. Not important in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should not include the leading ampersand, and you should also not concatenate raw parameters together unless you know they're already URI encoded:

```
var paramList = [];
for (var n in params) {
    paramList.push(encodeURIComponent(n) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[n]));
}
var paramStr = paramList.join('&');
xhr.open(method, url + '?' + paramStr);
```

[Better yet, save yourself a whole load of hassle and just use jQuery which can do all this stuff for you properly cross-browser].

Comment: We don't know that the OP hasn't already URI encoded the parameter names and values in the `params` object.

Comment: I'm using Sencha Touch and don't want to add yet another library to the package. However, after reading your reply I checked Sencha's docs again and it turns out they have a nice Ext.Ajax.request method :)

Comment: @Andy - we don't know, but it's likely he didn't.  That's why I _explicitly_ said that you shouldn't roll your own _unless_ they already are.

Comment: @Vitaly, right, so you should just use the `params` parameter in the options to the `Ext.Ajax.request` call - `...({params: params});`

Answer (score 0):

do this instead, its much cleaner...

```
var paramStr = '';
for (var n in params) {
  var param = n + '=' + params[n];
  paramStr += paramStr == '' ? param : '&' + param
}
xhr.open(method, url + '?' + paramStr);
```

**EDIT**

Couldn't you just do?

```
params.join('&')
```

is that possible? what is the data structure like?

Comment: (Better to do it once afterwards than an if for every element.)

Answer (score 0):

Leaving it is ok, but find below the code modified that will prevent writing separators before the first element.

```
var paramStr = '';
var count=0;
for (var n in params) {
    paramStr += (count>0?'&':'') + n + '=' + params[n];
    count++;
}
xhr.open(method, url + '?' + paramStr);
```